# Scoping transactions and sessions in NHibernate for long running tasks

Tags: nhibernate, transactions, unit-of-work

When using NHibernate in web applications, I will usually let my IoC container take care of opening and closing an `ISession` per request and commit/rollback the transaction. The nature of HTTP makes it very easy to define a clear Unit-of-Work in such applications.

Now, I have been tasked with putting together a small program, which will be invoked regularly by a task scheduler, for sending out newsletters. The concepts of both newsletters and subscribers are already well defined entities in our domain model, and sending a newsletter to all subscribers would involve doing something similar to this:

```
var subscribers = _session
    .QueryOver<Subscription>()
    .Where(s => !s.HasReceivedNewsletter)
    .List();

foreach (var subscriber in subscribers)
{
    SendNewsletterTo(subscriber);
    subscriber.HasReceivedNewsletter = true;
}
```

Notice how each `Subscriber` object  is updated within the loop, recording that she has now received the newsletter. The idea is, that if the mail sending program should crash, it can be restarted and continue sending newsletters from where it left off.

The problem I am facing, is in defining and implementing the Unit-of-Work pattern here. I will probably need to commit changes to the database by the end of each iteration of the loop. Simply wrapping the loop body with a `using (var trans = _session.BeginTransaction())` block seems to be extremely expensive in running time, and I also seem to experience locking issues between this long running process and other (web) applications using the same database.

After reading some articles and documentation on NHibernate transactions, I have come to think, that I might need to detach the list of subscribers from the session to avoid the locking issues, and reattach each to a fresh session in the loop body. I am not sure how this will work for performance, though.

So, NHibernate experts, how would you design and implement a long running job like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't you think that Stateless session with no transaction will do better here?

Comment: Never heard of it before, but from the first few lines on Google it looks like it might be the case. Please, tell me more about how and why it will solve my problems :)

Comment: I am going to accept this answer due to the "stateless session" hint. However, I am holding back my upvote, hoping that @Sly (or anyone else) will expand a bit on the subject, for the good of the community :)

Comment: A stateless session can't do a dynamic update to only the HasReceivedNewsletter flag, there will later be an update to the full Subscriber row, or you have to update it manually, perhaps by HQL update. A stateless session is like no session at all, only using NHibernate to cast database rows into NHibernate objects.

Answer (score 1):

Don't you want to use asynchronous durable messaging here? Something like NServiceBus, Rhino Service Bus or MassTransit. It seems you don't have to send a lot of messages as soon as possible, so I think you should do it asynchronously with 1 durable message per user basis

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem having multiple transactions in a session. It's appropriate here to scope the transaction to updating a single subscriber because it's an independent operation. Depending on the number of subscribers and the likelihood of failure, it might be best to grab a small number of subscribers at a time.

```
foreach (var subscriber in subscribers)
{
    using (var txn = _session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            SendNewsletterTo(subscriber);
            subscriber.HasReceivedNewsletter = true;
            txn.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            txn.Rollback();
            // log exception, clean up any actions SendNewsletterTo has taken if needed
            // Dispose of session and start over
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: You will probably not need an explicit transaction for this - this loop shall create atomic single update commands.